# How to specify the return type of a simple mapper function that maps an array of data in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mapping

How can I get TypeScript to give me type-safety and throw an Error in simple mapper functions like this?

```
export function mapFoosToBars(foos: Array<Foo>): Array<Bar> {
    return foos.map(foo => ({
        b: foo.a,
        c: foo.a, // <-- Why no TypeScript Error here?
    }));
}

type Foo = {
    a: string;
};

type Bar = {
    b: string;
};
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwLYCGYAYhBAM4AqEAQgVOQBQJnkBccAglFAQJ4AeUhAB8ASg7degulBFwA3gCg4quFGAwkUXCwoA6QmGZk4AXnmNlam3ABGHPfoIAaFbdVpHZZy7gB6fzgBAFoQuAB3AAs%20OBQIOBg%20MGByNChMMHhgHmg4KJzgAH53VQBfMTEAbiUypSUklLhhc0VSuAIOchgMlABzGrKahuTgOFlW6zUHOG7egdqaoA)

Comment: Why would you want that to be an error?

Comment: Well usually since its indicates that someone forgot to add some field to the type. 
We use only exact types. This is just a simple example. There are other more advanced mapper we have where it makes more sense.

Comment: To be more concrete:
lets say you have another field in `Bar` called `ca?: string`
then the correct mapper line should have been `ca: foo.a` and the type in line `c: foo.a` won't show any error.

Comment: What you are complaining about is known as subtype polymorphism, a cornerstone of most type systems.

Comment: Was not meant to be a complaint, just need to solve the issues when mapping arrays of data we want to keep the type safety on a exact type level. We have had more than one bug because of this in our mapper functions.

Comment: I shouldn't have used the word complaining. I understand what you're saying, but I disagree with you when you say if **"you have another field in `Bar` called `ca?: string` then the correct mapper line should have been `ca: foo.a`"**. Yes, it's a bug in your scenario but I don't think that can be generalized. There are very few places where exact types are enforced. One way to flag that mistake though would be to remove the return type annotation. Then you would get an error at the use site `if (mapFoosToBars([{a: "X"}]).some(bar => bar.ca?.toLowerCase() === "x"))`. My gripe is philosophical:)

Comment: While by no means always the case, I find that TS users often over annotate code resulting in less specific types being inferred and propagated (like `string` instead of `“success" | "failure"` as a return type because they thought it was dogma to annotate everything) and sometimes even creating hidden type assertions (like annotating the parameter types of inline callbacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no TypeScript error because `map` infers the predicate's return type to be `{ b: string; c: string }`, and since this type is assignable to `Bar`, it is legal. If you want to properly guard against excess properties, you have to explicitly annotate the return type of the predicate:

```
export function mapFoosToBars(foos: Array<Foo>): Array<Bar> {
    return foos.map((foo): Bar => ({
        b: foo.a,
        c: foo.a, // error
    }));
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwLYCGYAYhBAM4AqEAQgVOQBQJnkBccAglFAQJ4AeUhAB8ASg7degulBFwA3gCg4quFGAwkUXCwoA6QmEbMyEuLLgBeeYwVwVapwCMOe-QQA0jp6rRuyD28nAF8xMQBuJRClJRg+MGA4YWtFHzgCDnIYKEwUAHMokKi4hKTLKzSXLJy8wuiooA)

---

Oddly... passing a generic instead is bugged... `foos.map<Bar>` will not guard against excess properties.

Comment: `foos.map<Bar>` not guarding against excess properties is not bugged. The excess prop check only takes place when a freshly created object literal is directly assigned to an object typed location. Consider `let b: Bar = {b: foo.a,  c: foo.a}` vs `let b: Bar = {...foo}` or `let b: Bar = {...{a: foo.a, c: foo.c}}`. The latter 2 are indirect as is the type argument which indicates to the return type of mapping fn. By the way, passing type arguments explicitly is bad code in 99.9% of cases